# Is there a KeyboardType for emojies in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

Is there a keyboardtype that shows the emojies of the keyboard or is there any package (not the EmojiPicker) that implements such for Flutter? Unfortunately I can't include the EmojiPicker in the normal keyboard. So the package is not an option for me. The best option would be one that calls the normal emoji keyboard. Are there any commands or functions for this?

Answer (score 1):

Just use `emoji_picker_flutter: ^1.3.1`

```
EmojiPicker(
    onEmojiSelected: (category, emoji) {
        // Do something when emoji is tapped (optional)
    },
    onBackspacePressed: () {
        // Do something when the user taps the backspace button (optional)
    },
    textEditingController: textEditionController, // pass here the same [TextEditingController] that is connected to your input field, usually a [TextFormField]
    config: Config(
        columns: 7,
        emojiSizeMax: 32 * (Platform.isIOS ? 1.30 : 1.0), // Issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/28894
        verticalSpacing: 0,
        horizontalSpacing: 0,
        gridPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        initCategory: Category.RECENT,
        bgColor: Color(0xFFF2F2F2),
        indicatorColor: Colors.blue,
        iconColor: Colors.grey,
        iconColorSelected: Colors.blue,
        progressIndicatorColor: Colors.blue,
        backspaceColor: Colors.blue,
        skinToneDialogBgColor: Colors.white,
        skinToneIndicatorColor: Colors.grey,
        enableSkinTones: true,
        showRecentsTab: true,
        recentsLimit: 28,
        noRecents: const Text(
          'No Recents',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.black26),
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ),
        tabIndicatorAnimDuration: kTabScrollDuration,    
        categoryIcons: const CategoryIcons(),
        buttonMode: ButtonMode.MATERIAL,
    ),
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are some alternatives to emoji_picker package; https://pub.dev/packages?q=emoji+picker+keyboard but also the [package you said](https://pub.dev/packages/emoji_picker) it's deprecated and replaced by this one https://pub.dev/packages/emoji_picker_flutter

Comment: Thank you, but I have already searched all the packets at pub.dev and have unfortunately remained without success. Why I would like to include the EmojieKeyboard directly in the normal keyboard is so that I can save myself the rescaling when switching between keyboard and emojies when pressing a button outside of the keyboard.